# Does the array the name point to the address of the 0th element?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a silly doubt .
Say suppose I have a array int a[]={3,4,5,6}
now I want to know if  the address of this array points to the location of only 3 or the entire array elements?

Comment: An array is an array. However `a` can decay to a pointer to the first element of the array in certain contexts

Comment: The address of `a` will point to the first element of `a` (`a[0]`).

Comment: The address of an array points to the array.  It just so happens that that location is also the address of the first element of the array.

Comment: A pointer to the first element of an array, only points to the first element of the array. However by incrementing that pointer you get a pointer to the second element of the array, and so on. So essentially you are correct.

Comment: @mdf -- it's more subtle than that. The address of the array is the address of the array. It doesn't point at anything, because it's not a pointer. The **name** of the array decays into a pointer to its first element in most contexts. So `int *p = a;` sets `p` to point at the first element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

The address of the array points to the array. And that is the same address as the address of the first element.

However, they are not the same type. `&a` is a pointer to an array with 4 elements, `int(*)[4]`. `&a[0]` is a pointer to a single `int`, an `int*`. Because arrays can decay to pointers to their first element (for example when passed to a function) those two are often confused.